# "A problem repeatedly occurred" - Website keeps crashing on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari, fullpage.js

I have a website which seems to crash on iOS devices with an error message of "A problem repeatedly occurred". I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I have implemented lazy loading, minification, caching etc. I have tried removing all of the CSS and this did not fix the issue.

Any help would be much much appreciated. The only thing I can think of now is that the web page is too large (file size). There's a lot of full screen images etc. Is there a limit at which iOS Safari just gives up do you think?

TIA

Comment: My tip? Start removing HTML code bit by bit until the error goes away. Once it  goes away you'll  know the element you removed (HTML element, script, stylesheet...) is the one causing the issue.

Comment: I have tried reducing a lot of css filters, transform but not working. Suffering with this for a long time. Don't have an iphone. This page crashes immediately https://elomymelo.com/ but some mobile responsive pages of my site loads but on scroll it crashes https://elomymelo.com/soundcore-boost-review.html My website has a width of 3554px, which probably causing memory problem. But older ios like 13 or lower loads those pages fine. Did you get any solutions?